# What is the proper way to prevent an Ansible playbook from updating a config file after it has been updated

Tags: ansible

I'm working on a playbook to manage a webserver I host multiple domains on. I have one config that sets up my nginx server and then another that manages my certificates.   As of now the work flow is as follows:

1. Copy template for virtual host to server, NGINX is restarted
2. Certificates are generated
3. Remote NGINX config files are updated (using lineinfile), NGINX is restarted

This works great unless I run the playbook because my template file would overwrite the remote file.  I'd still like to be able to run the same playbook to run down the road if I need to make any updates to my host configs but I'm at a loss how to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use lineinfile. Manage complete files with one or more template tasks.

Should you decide to separate the roles for  nginx config and getting certificates, they will need to coordinate somehow. Perhaps the nginx role just assumes Let's Encrypt default cert locations.  Or, perhaps you can set variables like `nginx_ssl_certificate: /etc/pki/tls/certs/{{ inventory_hostname }}/cert.crt`  assuming that the domain name is the name in inventory.

If the nginx role runs first, and configures a certificate that does not exist, nginx will not start. Consider using a handler for nginx restart, which will be deferred until a later stage in the play. Or, reorder the roles so the cert exists first.

---

Idempotent tasks with lineinfile is possible, but it requires understanding lineinfile's various modes, and writing regexes. I don't recommend it, lineinfile confuses everyone.